# How can I use induction to show that all hexagonal numbers are odd?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction, recurrence-relations

How can I use induction to show that all hexagonal numbers are odd? The following recurrence relation gives the hexagonal numbers: $1$ if $n=1$ and $H(n-1)+6n-6$ if $n>1$

I only want to use only the recurrence relation provided.

Comment: If a hexagonal number is odd, then the next one is clearly odd, as it is equal to the previous one plus a multiple of $6$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove this by induction, you need to show that

1. $H_1$ is odd, and
2. for all $n>1$, **if** $H_{n-1}$ is odd **then** $H_n$ is also odd.

Can you see how 2. follows from the recurrence relation (what can you say about $6n-6$)?

Comment: That $6n-6$ will have the same parity as $6n$?

Comment: And is $6n$ odd or even?

Comment: Even. An even number (six in this case) times any integer will result in an even product.

Comment: Oh, I think I got it. Since we're starting off with an odd number, adding evens from thence on will ensure that the rest of the sequence is odd. Is this the inductive step?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Alright. Thanks, Especially Lime!